# Как изменить путь к файлу .json в приложении

Tags: java, android, json, path

У меня есть класс, который указывает путь к файлу **.json** лежащему в папке приложения **assets/station/file.json**

Допустим, я сделал так, чтоб приложение скачивало файл .json из интернета и его сохраняло в памяти телефона, в какой-либо папке (допустим **E:\my_folder\file.json**).

Вопрос стоит в том, что я не могу понять, как и что мне нужно изменить в этом классе, чтобы приложение перестало брать этот файл json по этому пути до папки **assets/station/..** , а брало из папки **E:\my_folder\file.json** ??

```
public class Directory {

    private static final String TAG = Log.buildTag(Directory.class);
    private static List<Station> stations = null;

    private static Map<String, Station> stationIndex = new HashMap<>();

    public static void loadStations(final Context context) {
        stations = new ArrayList<>();

        final AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();

        String paths[] = new String[0];
        try {
            paths = assetManager.list("stations");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error loading stations", e);
            return;
        }

        for (String path : paths) {
            if (!path.endsWith(".json"))
                continue;
            final Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Station>>() {}.getType();
            List<Station> chunk = null;
            try {
                chunk = gson.fromJson(new InputStreamReader(assetManager.open("stations/" + path), "UTF-8"), listType);
                stations.addAll(chunk);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "error loading station: %s", e, path);
            }
        }

        Station.sort(stations);

        indexStations(stations);

    }

    private static void indexStations(final List<Station> stations) {
        stationIndex.clear();

        for (Station station : stations) {
            stationIndex.put(station.getStationUrl(), station);
        }
    }

    public static List<Station> getStations() {
        return stations;
    }

    public static Station getStation(final String url) {
        return stationIndex.get(url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, будет проще написать еще один метод, скажем `loadStationsFromFile`, где вместо `AssetManager` будете использовать `File` для доступа к файлу согласно его пути, который вы знаете.
Можно этот путь передавать как параметр метода.

Answer (score 0):

Надо вместо `assetManager.open("station/file.json")` использовать `FileInputStream("E:\\my_folder\\file.json")`